# C# Regex replace using Dictionary

Tags: c#, regex, replace, idictionary

I am looking for an option to replace multiple characters of a string in  one go. I'm trying to pass a string as a parameter for a URL which has special characters like," **/,+,(,),#**". So I need to do some encoding. In one of SO questions I came across this option [Regex Replace](http://rextester.com/SXXB8348)

Below is the code

```
var input = "Product name A/C 2+2 (Mod #1)";
var space = "%20";
var slash = "%2F";
var plus = "%2B";
var open = "%28";
var hashV = "%23";
var close = "%29";            
var replacements = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
   {" ",space},
   {"/",slash},
   {"+",plus},
   {"(",open},
   {"#",hashV},
   {")",close}
};

var regex = new Regex(String.Join("|",replacements.Keys));
var replaced = regex.Replace(input,m => replacements[m.Value]);
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

I am getting the following error

```
System.ArgumentException: parsing " |/|+|(|#|)" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.
```

but if I `comment out` **plus, open** and **close** I'm getting the output without any problem for those replacements.

`Product%20name%20A%2FC%202+2%20(Mod%20%231)`

Why replace doesn't work for these characters?
Am I doing something wrong here?If there is any other way to solve this, I'm willing to try that too. But I want to understand this better.

Comment: escape the `()` brackets.

Comment: I wonder where it gets the `Quantifier {x,y}` from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with using a dictionary - it's simply because you're using characters with special meaning in regular expressions (`+`, `(` and `)`) without quoting them. You'd get the same issue if you simply had `value = Regex.Replace(input, "(", "%28")`

You could use `Regex.Escape` to fix this though:

```
var regex = new Regex(String.Join("|",replacements.Keys.Select(Regex.Escape)));
```

Are you sure there isn't a built-in escaping method which does what you want though, e.g. a URL encoder? such as [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)? (I'm not an expert on URL encoding, and there may be some subtleties here - I would advise you to use an existing encoder rather than rolling your own though.)